# Find sequence in set S that converges to supremum of S.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

The full question is:

> Suppose $u = sup(S)$, where $S$ is a nonempty bounded set in $\mathbb R$. Show that there is a sequence $s_n$ in $S$ such that $s_n \rightarrow u$.

I was wondering if I simply say that any sequence $s_n$ in $S$ that contains $\max \{S\}$ converges to $u$ by the monotonic convergence theorem by definition.

The reasoning being that since any bounded, monotonic increasing sequence converges to the supremum of the sequence, $s_n$, which is contained within a set with the supremum of $u$, would also converge to $u$.

Does that work, or do I need to be more rigorous?

Comment: Not quite done. How do you know there is a bounded monotonic increasing sequence converging to the supremum? Finding such a sequence is the whole point of the exercise. Use the definition of the supremum to do that.

Comment: Remember that $\sup(S)$ need not be in $S$ so you cannot always construct a sequence $s_n$ in $S$ that contains $\sup(S)$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of the supremum of S, for every $\epsilon>0$ there is a point $x\in S$ such that $$\sup(S)-\epsilon<x.$$
This implies that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there is a point $x_n\in S$ such that 
$$x_n>\sup(S)-\frac 1 n.$$
This inequality shows that $x_n\to \sup(S).$